# Under which conditions is full rated power instead of METO power required for takeoff (DC-3/C-47 with Pratt&Whitney 1830 twin wasp engines)?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff

OK, so my explanation is going to be quite long, but please bear with me. My question is in two parts, but first I'll explain what I know.

I was reading the C-47 Pilot's Flight Operating Instructions and the DC-3 Organisation Control Manual, and they both say that takeoff should be performed at full-rated power. 
[This link](http://www.douglasdc3.com/dc3throt/dc3throt.htm) shows a bunch of good reasons why **one should always use maximum power for takeoff**

[*FAA mandatory for commercial operations; P&W endorse it;*

> 'The distance the pistons travel in the cylinders (stroke) is related
>   to the power used. The piston rings, over time, wear a ridge into the
>   cylinder wall at the top and bottom of the stroke. If 42" is used for
>   takeoff, the bottom ridge will develop further up the piston wall than
>   in an engine that has seen rated power for Takeoff. If the time comes
>   when full rated power is needed (short runway, engine failure, etc.)
>   and a power setting greater than 42" is used, the piston is now forced
>   past the ridge in the cylinder created by many hours of using de-rated
>   power. Forcing the piston rings past this ridge can cause them to
>   break'

*;carburator has additional cooling feature past 45"; engines last longer]*,

but also mentions the fact that **full-rated should only be used for one minute** at a time (which is apparently one of the reasons some people choose to *take off with METO power instead*).

One minute sounds like a very short time to me (and to the person defending T/O with METO power), but I'm not a pilot, so I do not know how long a  normal T/O roll with a DC-3 at maximum takeoff power  would take.

The DC-3 performance information sheet ([found here](http://pcmuseum.tripod.com/dc3/dc3performanceinformation.pdf)) mentions that (at sea level and normal runway conditions) a 1700 ft T/O roll is enough to reach 100 mph (which I am assuming is the minimum takeoff speed ), but it says nothing about how long  the DC-3 would take to reach that.

They also mention that at 5000 ft altitude it'd take a 2300 ft T/O roll to attain that same speed. But that still doesn't tell me how long that would take because I don't know the acceleration rate the DC-3 has. I've checked the charts, but I admit I couldn't conclude anything from them (doc is semi-readable, plus, it might have been way over my head anyway). I'm sorry if this question is stupid, maybe I need to brush off my physics , but I really am not managing to figure this one out on my own ...

I am aware there are a number of variables that come into play here, but I'd be happy if anyone could give me an approximation , or even an example of what conditions need to exist for the **DC-3 to take only a minute to do the T/O roll** (if one wanted to use *full-rated power*).
And, more importantly: Would a **wet grass runway** at an almost **6000 ft altitude** airport, plus having the aircraft at **maximum takeoff weight** (or close to it) justify choosing to *take off with METO* instead of full-rated power? I mean, such a T/O roll would definitely take over a minute, right?

Thanks a lot

Comment: “The distance the pistons travel in the cylinders (stroke) is related to the power used.” What? That makes no sense. The piston is connected to the crankshaft by a solid rod, so it must always travel the same range during each complete revolution.

Comment: @ Jan - I quoted it from the link provided ipsis litteris. I felt tempted to edit that part out because I thought it was too long, but as I'm not a pilot or engineer I feared I'd  make a mistake, so I copied exactly what was written there). thanks

Comment: @ Jan - anyway, that part is not what really  mattered to me. I'm interested in valid reasons for taking off with METO power. Mainly the ones I asked about, but not restricted to those. The reason I added that info was to avoid getting answers that would tell me that no one should take off without full-rated speed (and then list those reasons). I took it from a website that seems to be trustworthy and the people that wrote that have been flying DC-3s for a long time... Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand you quoted it as you got it. I am saying it does not sound right. And it's not like it was official documentation anyway. And I also understand it is not the actual question—that's why I wrote a comment, *not* an answer.

Comment: @ Jan - no , that wasn't in the official docs. One captain mentions it throughout the text and the one that is presumably in charge of the page also mentions it at the beginning , seemingly in agreement. Let me get his quote for you. give me a sec

Comment: 'It has been found of late, that de-rated power takeoffs can cause the piston rings to break, because they create a ridge at each end of the cylinders end walls, thereby, when ever full power is needed such as a "single engine out emergency" problem may occur with engine cylinders caused by breakage of the piston rings. Incidentally, Pratt & Whitney endorse the use of full power contrary to there own report in 1953 advising to use de-rated power at the time.'  it's a different person speaking now  (quote from http://www.douglasdc3.com/dc3throt/dc3throt.htm )       thanks

Comment: @ Jan - the way he put it, "it has been found of late" , made me think it was a fact. I don't know better so it didn't cross my mind to dispute it. apologies for that. Do you reckon I should edit that part out to avoid changing the focus of the debate?

Comment: There is nothing to apologise for. And there is no need to change it; answers and comments are separate.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a really good question. Don't feel sorry for its length as it add a lot of precision and make the answers more specific

Comment: @ Manu H - thank you for that. I felt tempted to  delete this yesterday because I felt a bit daft. I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @JanHudec - reading through the linked page, I think there's some confusion. I initially thought the same thing you did - there's no way the piston stroke can change (and a 42" stroke sounds like a marine diesel, not an aviation engine)! I think the 42" refers to manifold pressure. I think that (maybe) increasing that MP to full power (48"?) can cause the piston to hit top/bottom _harder_? than normal causing the rings to fracture when they hit those ridges. Still not sure that's 100% accurate, but it's the only logical thing I can make of it. (con't...

Comment: ... the 42 v 48" MP comes from the _DC-3 Throttle's Management_ section of the link, while the cylinder ridge formation comes from point 1 under the _Some differing opinions and interesting information:_ section. I've gotta admit - it explicitly says the piston stroke varies, and that's just mind-boggling to me...

Comment: Dang. There's an email contact link on that page, but the mailbox is full. I sent a question asking about this.

Comment: That part about piston travel is a misprint or just an error. It's piston velocity that increases as RPM increases in the engine. Piston velocity is a useful measure for determine the breaking point of an engine, as there are some pretty obvious limits to it.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. As this is too hard for me to understand having no background in engineering or aviation, I won't comment any further. but  I'm also curious as to what they meant (as all of you are in agreement that it makes no sense) . Do let us know what they say if you can get that email to go through, please,  @FreeMan

Comment: @DeltaLima - thank you so much for helping out with the readability of this question. it looks a million times better. I don't know how to do that (the link to another page without showing the actual address and the indented quotation). Would you mind sending me a link that explains how to do that? I had a hard enough time trying to add a picture to another SE lol . thanks a lot

Comment: @DeltaLima - I went into "edit mode" and saw what you did. I think I understood it. Putting it to test now. Thank you so much for that

Comment: Steel is elastic, isn't it?  A piston rod must see quite a bit of tension when decelerating the piston.  It's not inconceivable to me that there's enough force to stretch the rod a little, with higher RPMs causing more tension and therefore more stretch.  What I don't know is how much stretch--could it be enough to account for the advice the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider your case of a 2300 ft (700 m) takeoff roll. Your link lists the procedure as reducing power upon reaching 90 kt (46 m/s). To make things easier we can assume constant acceleration. That won't be true in real life but it will give us an approximation.

Two basic equations for acceleration, relating distance $s$, acceleration $a$, time $t$, and velocity $v$:

$s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$

$a=\frac{\Delta v}{t}$

Substituting our known values in, we get:

$700\ \mathrm m=\frac{1}{2}at^2$

$a=\frac{46\ \mathrm{m/s}}{t}$

Soving for $t$, we get about 30 seconds (and $a=1.5\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$). Even accounting for acceleration reducing as speed increases, that suggests there's plenty of room to reach 90 knots in less than one minute.

If we look at what takeoff roll would result if we need 60 seconds to reach 90 knots, we get 1380 m, or 4500 ft.

To verify this you can also look up videos of DC-3 takeoffs. Like this one, which seems to take about 30 seconds:

I agree with the comments, piston travel changing significantly with power setting does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you @fooot for taking the time to help me with this conundrum. I apologise for my unintentionally  (mis)leading you to think both pieces of  info came from the same link. I've added the second link now to correct that. But it should still make sense given that both links talk about the same machine, right?    Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'd have never figured this out on my own. I didn't think of using two equations to substitute the missing variable and didn't realise it'd be ok to assume constant acceleration, so I'd have never come to that conclusion myself. So 60s doesn't seem that little after all, even at 5000ft altitude, and apparently the weight (according to the second link) doesn't account for that much difference either. So would the wet grass runway (in my example) account for the only reason to use METO for T/O ? thanks a lot

Comment: And how much do you guys reckon the heat would affect that (the first link says "heat gives the 5,000 ft ASL field a density altitude of 8,000 ft") ? Would I calculate the length of the T/O roll as if the altitude of the airport were actually 8,000 ft? Would any of you disagree that the weight makes little difference (second link says so, but I saw a number of links that attributed longer takeoff rolls to the aircraft being fully loaded and thus very heavy)?

Comment: Both heat and a grass runway would reduce the acceleration, it's hard to read the performance document but I didn't see any hints about how much difference those factors would make.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not the best copy. Sorry about that. I didn't see any mention of that either (in any of the DC-3 docs I found). the only variable the "take-off" text mentions (second link)  is the  altitude of the airport . and it also says changes in gross weight would not be very noticeable at sea level ...  Am I to assume that they'd make a difference at higher altitudes? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, as altitude increases, takeoff distance gets longer, and differences like weight start to be more noticeable. You can see in the takeoff runway required chart, at sea level the lowest two weights differ by 500 feet length, at 6000 feet they differ by 1000.

Comment: I was not able to make sense of the charts,  and the one I thought mattered the most was  scarcely readable to me, but perhaps that was because I wasn't sure what I was looking for (I couldn't wrap my head around the concepts that this matter entailed until you explained them to me) . I will take another look. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Connecting rods stretch/rod caps oval at high rpm. .030" is a common assumption for automotive engines with forged steel rods. 

I've always heard it discussed (again, in auto engines) as solely an rpm function rather than a power setting function. But the document cited does make a point of discussing the bottom ring land, which makes sense if you're dealing with an effect of power rather than rpm. Whereas auto excursions related to rpm are more about the top ring land because most of the flex is in caps/cap bolts, which is all stretch/ minimal compression.